# How to block diagonalize a real skew-symmetric matrix of 3*3

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, numerical-linear-algebra, rotations

Suppose $t = [t_1,t_2,t_3]^T\in \mathbb R^3,t \neq 0$. Then define
$$t^{\land} = \begin{bmatrix} 0   & -t_3 & t_2 \\
                              t_3 & 0    & -t_1\\ 
                             -t_2 & t_1  & 0\end{bmatrix},
Z=                           \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\
                                             -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$
According to [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)), there exist a corresponding rotation matrix 
$$R = \exp(t^{\land})$$
if $t^{\land}$ can be block diagonalized, that is
$$t^{\land} = U\begin{bmatrix} aZ & 0 \\
                               0  & 0\end{bmatrix}U^T,a>0$$
then we get $R = \exp(t^{\land})=U\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\|t\|_2)&\sin(\|t\|_2) & 0\\
                        -\sin(\|t\|_2)&\cos(\|t\|_2)&0 \\
                         0           & 0            &1\end{bmatrix}U^T,a=\|t\|_2$.

(refer to R.Hartley & A.Zisserman [*Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision*](http://cvrs.whu.edu.cn/downloads/ebooks/Multiple%20View%20Geometry%20in%20Computer%20Vision%20(Second%20Edition).pdf) page 583 to 584.)
So how to do block diagonalization in 3*3 case? And what is $U$ like?

Comment: Extend $w=t/\|t\|_2$ to an orthonormal basis $\{u,v,w\}$. Then take $U=\pmatrix{u,v,w}$.

Comment: @user1551 hello, i apply your thread(see following post of mine) while leads to a contradiction, can you help me out?

Comment: I didn't noticed that you need $a>0$. If you want to enforce this constraint and you  find that with your chosen $u,v$ the cross product $v\times u$ is $-w$ rather than $w$, you may simply interchange $u$ and $v$. Alternatively, replace $v$ by $-v$.

Comment: @user1551 But $det(U) = -1$ once I interchange $u \text{ and } v$ or negate $v$. Is it reasonable for an orthonormal matrix?

Comment: Why not? Your question doesn't require that $\det(U)=1$. Anyway, since it sets $Z$ to $\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&0}$ rather than $\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$, the determinant of $U$ has to be $-1$: when $u$ is orthogonal to $t$, the effect of $t\times u$ in the tangential direction is an anticlockwise rotation of $u$ about the directed axis $t$. However, $Z=\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&0}$ represents a clockwise rotation. So, in the change-of-basis matrix $U$, you must incorporate a reflection to preserve the sign, meaning that $\det(U)$ has to be $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

[image]

let $w=t/\|t\|$, then we take three orthonormal basis which form a orthonormal matrix $U = [u,v,w]$.Therefore
$$\begin{align} Udiag(aZ,0)U^T&=[u,v,w]\begin{bmatrix}
                0 & a & 0 \\
                -a & 0 & 0 \\
                 0 &  0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} u^T \\ v^T \\ w^T \end{bmatrix} \\
&=a(uv^T-vu^T) \\
&=a\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & u_1v_2-u_2v_1 & u_1v_3-u_3v_1 \\
u_2v_1-u_1v_2 & 0 & u_2v_3-u_3v_2 \\
u_3v_1-u_1v_3  & u_3v_2-u_2v_3 & 0\end{bmatrix} \\
&=a(v \times u)^{\land}\end{align} $$
So above derivation leads to 
$$t^{\land} = a(v \times u)^{\land}$$that is
$$t = a*(-w) = \|t\|(-w)$$
but it contradicts with $t = \|t\|w$, who can help?